# How to IEnumerable query in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a quick question. I have a table named categories and i want to list as `SelectListItem`. So far I tried with this code:

```
_context.Categories.ToList();
_context.Categories.AsIEnumerable();
```

but no luck.

How do I query my table as `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var selectListItems= _context.Categories
.Select(i=> new SelectListItem {
Value=i.Id.ToString(),
Text=i.Name
}).ToList(); // or .ToArray() it will be a little more sufficient As enumerable
```

Comment: I think this will work but i got some error Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name . i guess i have problem with quering database.

Comment: I solve that problem and your code works fine. many thanks to you.